# How do I center this page?

Tags: html, css, center

How do I center this page? I'm a noob. Thanks!

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Tech Time Out Pledge</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- Save for Web Styles (ttofb.psd) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
                function loadConversionPixel(){
                $('#ho-pixels').append('<iframe src="http://strk.gnlinks.com/SLv3" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1" height="1" onload=”changeLocation();”></iframe>');
   }
</script>

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-54408410-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--

#Table_01 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 width:900px;
 height:1000px;
}

#ttofb-01 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 width:900px;
 height:139px;
}

#ttofb-02 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:139px;
 width:318px;
 height:744px;
}

#ttofb-03 {
 position:absolute;
 left:318px;
 top:139px;
 width:65px;
 height:73px;
}

#ttofb-04 {
 position:absolute;
 left:383px;
 top:139px;
 width:149px;
 height:861px;
}

#ttofb-05 {
 position:absolute;
 left:532px;
 top:139px;
 width:303px;
 height:48px;
}

#ttofb-06 {
 position:absolute;
 left:835px;
 top:139px;
 width:65px;
 height:861px;
}

#ttofb-07 {
 position:absolute;
 left:532px;
 top:187px;
 width:303px;
 height:440px;
}

#ttofb-08 {
 position:absolute;
 left:318px;
 top:212px;
 width:65px;
 height:671px;
}

#ttofb-09 {
 position:absolute;
 left:532px;
 top:627px;
 width:121px;
 height:259px;
}

#ttofb-10 {
 position:absolute;
 left:653px;
 top:627px;
 width:107px;
 height:43px;
}

#ttofb-11 {
 position:absolute;
 left:760px;
 top:627px;
 width:75px;
 height:259px;
}

#ttofb-12 {
 position:absolute;
 left:653px;
 top:670px;
 width:107px;
 height:216px;
}

#ttofb-13 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:883px;
 width:58px;
 height:117px;
}

#ttofb-14 {
 position:absolute;
 left:58px;
 top:883px;
 width:287px;
 height:37px;
}

#ttofb-15 {
 position:absolute;
 left:345px;
 top:883px;
 width:38px;
 height:117px;
}

#ttofb-16 {
 position:absolute;
 left:532px;
 top:886px;
 width:34px;
 height:114px;
}

#ttofb-17 {
 position:absolute;
 left:566px;
 top:886px;
 width:262px;
 height:36px;
}

#ttofb-18 {
 position:absolute;
 left:828px;
 top:886px;
 width:7px;
 height:114px;
}

#ttofb-19 {
 position:absolute;
 left:58px;
 top:920px;
 width:287px;
 height:80px;
}

#ttofb-20 {
 position:absolute;
 left:566px;
 top:922px;
 width:262px;
 height:78px;
}

-->
</style>
<!-- End Save for Web Styles -->
</head>
<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (ttofb.psd) -->
<div id="Table_01">
 <div id="ttofb-01">
  <img src="images/ttofb_01.gif" width="900" height="139" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div id="ttofb-02">
  <img src="images/ttofb_02.gif" width="318" height="744" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div id="ttofb-03"><fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/techtimeout" send="false" layout="box_count" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
 //facebook code
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({appId: '116284395201493', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
   // Do something, e.g. track the click on the "Like" button here
   loadConversionPixel();
   // push click to Google Analytics 
   _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Social', 'Clicked', 'Facebook']);
  });
 };
 (function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script');
  e.type = 'text/javascript';
  e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  e.async = true;
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
 }());
//-->
</script></div>
 <div id="ttofb-04">
  <img src="images/ttofb_04.gif" width="149" height="861" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div id="ttofb-05"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/TechTimeOut/app_164858677009603"><img src="images/ttofb_05.gif" width="303" height="48" alt="" /></a>
 </div>
 <div id="ttofb-06">
  <img src="images/ttofb_06.gif" width="65" height="861" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div id="ttofb-07">
  <img src="images/ttofb_07.gif" width="303" height="440" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div id="ttofb-08">
  <img src="images/ttofb_08.gif" width="65" height="671" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div id="ttofb-09"> <a href="http://techtimeout.com/technology-ruining-family-vacation/"><img src="images/ttofb_09.gif" width="121" height="259" alt="" /></a>
 </div>
 <div id="ttofb-10"> <a href="http://www.facebook.com/TechTimeOut"><img src="images/ttofb_10.gif" width="107" height="43" alt="" /></a>
 </div>
 <div id="ttofb-11">
  <img src="images/ttofb_11.gif" width="75" height="259" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div id="ttofb-12"> <a href="http://techtimeout.com/technology-ruining-family-vacation/"><img src="images/ttofb_12.gif" width="107" height="216" alt="" /></a>
 </div>
 <div id="ttofb-13">
  <img src="images/ttofb_13.gif" width="58" height="117" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div id="ttofb-14"> <a href="http://www.facebook.com/TechTimeOut"><img src="images/ttofb_14.gif" width="287" height="37" alt="" /></a>
 </div>
 <div id="ttofb-15">
  <img src="images/ttofb_15.gif" width="38" height="117" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div id="ttofb-16">
  <img src="images/ttofb_16.gif" width="34" height="114" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div id="ttofb-17">
  <img src="images/ttofb_17.gif" width="262" height="36" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div id="ttofb-18">
  <img src="images/ttofb_18.gif" width="7" height="114" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div id="ttofb-19">
  <img src="images/ttofb_19.gif" width="287" height="80" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div id="ttofb-20">
  <img src="images/ttofb_20.gif" width="262" height="78" alt="" />
 </div>
</div>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
<div id="ho-pixels"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

(What else can i actually say to get this posted? It looks like my post is mostly code. This is true, because that's what I need help with. Is this enough details to get my question posted? Yes!)

Comment: What you _could_ do is explain what you tried, what you got and why it doesn't satisfy you. Also, this a pretty common question - googling or searching on stackoverflow should have provided plenty of answers.

Comment: Hi ivy,I tried googling and searching stackoverflow for an answer and attempted several different centering answers, but couldn't get it to work. This code was given to me to upload and then they asked me to center it.

Comment: ok so you searched, but we have no idea what you found and why it didn't work for you, that's my point. If you _have_ searched, mention it in the question - it can help avoid repeating the same answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the styles for `#Table_01` to the following;

```
#Table_01 {
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:900px;
    height:1000px; /* delete this line if you don't want a fixed height */
}
```

The `margin` property is set to `0` pixels for the top and bottom margin, and `auto` for left and right, which means the element will appear in the center of the page.

Hope this helps.